# Split a list of linq strings backwards for a search model

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

Apologies if this is badly worded.
I'm attempting to create a search model based on a list of strings using linq.
Each string has a selection of ID's from different tables in it and within the string I'm attempting to filter based on them. The string is what is causing me confusion as I need to split the string using _ but from the end of the string backwards as I have more control from the end of the string than from the beginning as the beginning of the string 'Name' can contain many _

The strings structure is:

```
Name_specific_SiteID_CountryID_PageID_DeviceID_PageName
```

Linq and Search Model

```
var result = (from a in context.Searchstrings
              where a.Name.Contains("_specific_")
              select a).ToList().AsQueryable();

if (searchModel != null)
{
    if (searchModel.SiteId.HasValue)
        result = result.Where(p => p.Name.Split('_').Count() - 5 == searchModel.SiteId);
```

[Vague example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PATt8.jpg) - 
The point of splitting the string is to use drop downs with the ID's matching the position on the string - so for SiteID I'm trying to split it and match searchModel.SiteId with SiteID from the dropdown in the position of *whatever*_specific_{SiteID}_*rest of string*

Comment: Does it have to be a string? A class with the separate items as properties would make it very much easier to use. Even a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) string would be less of a headache.

Comment: is `specific` always `"specific"`?

Comment: can you give a few examples of how the string look like and what you expect to get?

Comment: yeah the string is created by taking a name and adding the _specific_SiteID_CountryID_PageID_DeviceID_PageName when instructed.

Comment: @NathanYates - so the part of the string `_specific_` is literal?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are processing a list of names containing substring `_specific_`, you can split by `"_specific_"` and then split by `'_'`:

```
var result = (from a in context.Searchstrings
                where a.Name.Contains("_specific_")
                select a).ToList().AsQueryable();

if (searchModel != null)
{
    if (searchModel.SiteId.HasValue)
        result = result.Where(p => p.Name
            .Split("_specific_", StringSplitOptions.None).Last()
            .Split('_')[0] == searchModel.SiteId);
}
```

The first `Split` converts `Name_specific_SiteID_CountryID_PageID_DeviceID_PageName` into `Name` and `SiteID_CountryID_PageID_DeviceID_PageName`.

The reason I used `.Last` instead of `[1]` is that if there's any chance that `Name` contains `_specific_`, `.Split("_specific_", StringSplitOptions.None)[1]` will give you the wrong output.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement an extension of `string` to add a custom version of `Split()` that will work backward :

```
public static class MyExtension
{
    // input is the input string to split
    // limit is the number of desired substrings to output
    public static IEnumerable<string> ReverseSplit(this string input, int limit = 6)
    {
        var temp = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = input.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (input[i] == '_' && limit > 1)
            {
                yield return temp.ToString();
                temp.Clear();
                limit--;
            }
            else
            {
                temp.Insert(0, input[i]);
            }
        }

        // return the last element
        if (temp.Length > 0)
            yield return temp.ToString();
    }
}
```

Test program :

```
var input = "Name_with_underscore_specific_SiteID_CountryID_PageID_DeviceID_PageName";

foreach (var data in input.ReverseSplit())
{
    Console.WriteLine(data);
}
```

This outputs :

```
PageName
DeviceID
PageID
CountryID
SiteID
Name_with_underscore_specific
```

[Try it yourself](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8wF3rz)

Comment: You're fairly close to answering the question - if you had `int limit = 6` I think it'd be perfect.

Comment: @Enigmativity I wasn't sure if `name_specific` should have been treated as 1 or 2 elements

Comment: It seems like it is an identifier, so it probably works both ways for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
string text = "Name_specific_SiteID_CountryID_PageID_DeviceID_PageName";

string[] parts = text.Split('_').Reverse().Take(5).Reverse().ToArray();
string name = text.Substring(0, text.Length - parts.Sum(p => p.Length + 1));
```

Then `parts` is an array of:

```
SiteID 
CountryID 
PageID 
DeviceID 
PageName
```

With `parts[0]` being the `SiteID` and name being `Name_specific`.

Comment: Hi Enigmativity, when attempting this with result (the list of strings) I get IQueryable<T> does not contain split as I attempted a similar thing (                // string test = "Name_specific_SiteID_CountryID_PageID_DeviceID_PageName";
                //String[] ts = test.Split('_');
                //string country = ts[ts.Count() - 4];)

Comment: @NathanYates - Why make it `IQueryable<T>`? The list of strings should be an array.

Comment: @NathanYates - Also the code you posted in the comment above isn't the same as my code.

Answer (score 0):

Linq has a [Reverse method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.reverse?view=netframework-4.8)

```
string name = "Name_specific_SiteID_CountryID_PageID_DeviceID_PageName";
name.Split('_').Reverse()
```

results in

```
PageName
DeviceID
PageID
CountryID
SiteID
specific
Name
```

So

```
var siteId = name[4];
```

Comment: The question is about how you can get `SiteID` out of the string when there are a variable number of `_` before the `SiteID`. You haven't answered that.

Answer (score 0):

just a little correction as you would like to do something with the different strings that you get after splitting the original string.

```
string name = "Name_specific_SiteID_CountryID_PageID_DeviceID_PageName";
var splittedName = name.Split('_').Reverse();
```

Then, you can do whatever you want with `splittedName`.

```
var siteId = splittedName[4]
```

Comment: The question is about how you can get `SiteID` out of the string when there are a variable number of `_` before the `SiteID`. You haven't answered that.